# When to filter the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I noticed that the implementation of [_.extend](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L792) will copy over everything including the prototype chain.

I noticed that [_.each](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L77) will filter out properties on the prototype chain.

I would have expected `_.extend` to filter out properties on the protoype chain just by default.  If so `_.each` could have been used twice, instead of just once in the implementation of `_.extend`.

Why isn't the prototype chain filtered in `_.extend` similarly to how it is in `_.each`?

Comment: Is there a case where this matters for you? That would be a better question, otherwise, it's too theoretical for SO

Comment: You might get a better answer if you contact the developer(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation doesn't mention whether it reads the prototype chain.

From their code, `_.clone` method, they use `_.extend` to create a shallow copy. That's probably the real reason why `_.extend` reads the prototype chain... Not that it's a good reason.  However, I never use `_.extend` passing it anything but a raw object

Example of a reason why _.clone needs it

```
function Base(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

Base.prototype = {b: 'b'};    
var obj = new Base('a')

console.log($.clone({x: 'x'}, obj))

// Most people would expect the output to be
// {x: 'x',  a: 'a', b: 'b'}

// If it didn't read the prototype, it would only be
// {x: 'x',  a: 'a'}
```